# Is there are way to figure out in Apex if a field is required on Page Layout using the Describe or some other class?

Tags: apex

I know the following works for actually required fields (setup at the field level) but doesn't work for the fields which are made required at the page layout level.

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = Account.Industry.getDescribe();
System.debug(dfr.isNillable()); //Output is true
```

On the Account detail page, it is required:

[image]

Comment: You would need to call the Metadata API to get the page layouts, find the field(s), and check their properties.

Comment: You can use the [Operations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Metadata_Operations.htm) class to retrieve a layout, then parse that data to determine which fields are required.

Comment: What is the context for this? How are you telling the Apex which layout is being used?

Comment: TIL - The Metadata namespace class/methods fully supplant the Andy Fawcett MDAPI GitHub package? @sfdcfox

Comment: @cropredy only for layouts and CMT record handling. It is very limited.

Comment: @PhilW - ah, I glossed over the enumeration of subTypes and didn't realize they were all CMDT/layout-related.